# Is it possible to store values in another actions localdatasheet?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, qtp, ui-automation

Following is the scenario, i have 2 action

```
 1. Action_1
    a. Action_2
```

Action_1 store run time data in local sheet and i want to store Action_2 run time data in Action_1 local sheet.
is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store data in the local sheet of action 2 and call it from action 1 which would seem like essentially the same thing.

You would need to input a `RunAction"Action1"[Action1], StartRowNumber-EndRowNumber`

It may also be a good idea to break out code logic from test steps. You could manage your test steps in one action that calls other actions and refers to their code and datasheets. Hope I was able to provide some insight! :)